# Как использовать NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c

У меня есть текст и картинка. Картинка всегда на расстоянии от текста 10px.
Использую *autolayout* в *Interface Builder*. Могу я задать размер картинки программно, но при этом использовать *NSLayoutConstraint*, чтобы она смещалась на 10x?
Есть еще варианты решения вопроса, если мне нужно в одном *Image View* использовать разные картинки с разным отношением сторон?

Comment: Вы б, может, со своими предыдущими вопросами разобрались заодно.

Comment: На предыдущие не ответили. На этот как-то тоже. Нужно что-то добавить к вопросу?

Comment: на этот вряд ли будут отвечать, раз за вами водится нежелание заниматься своими вопросами. Один вопрос закрыт, как требующий правки - на него нельзя отвечать пока его не откроют. Его надо уточнить. второй даны два ответа, если ни один не подходит то и его стоит уточнить.